# Is a value (not a file) binary?

Tags: php, oracle, binary-data

I have a database that sends nearly all data as string/numeric values. One field has turned out to be binary. When I see a binary $value, I need to strtoupper(bin2hex($value)) to make it work with the rest of the code.

I see that PHP 6 will have an is_binary function. Right now, I am using this function, but I assume that there will be unexpected shortcomings. Please let me know if you see a blatant problem.

```
function is_binary($value)
{
    for($i=0;$i<strlen($value);$i++)
        if(ord($value{$i})>128)
            return true;
    return false;
}
```

The logic is that none of the alpha-numeric field values will have a character with an ASCII value above 128 and all binary values will.

For further reference, the database is Oracle and the troubling data is coming out of a column with type RAW.

Comment: "Binary data"...  All data can be represented as binary.  Do you mean a single octet/byte?

Comment: @Jamen In PHP, "binary" is clearly defined. For example, the hex2bin function does not spit out the same value with the semantic argument that the hex value was technically binary to begin with. I further explained that the data is coming from a RAW data type in Oracle, producing unprintable binary characters.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that will work. The data may be binary, but use bites that are lower that 128.

Besides that you can have a UTF-8 string for instance that has valid code points higher than 128 and that would be a string and not binary.

Answer (score 0):

The `RAW` data type simply means that Oracle will not do character set conversion or any other transformation on the column value when passing it to the application. The assumption is that it is the application itself that knows what kind of data are stored in the column and interpret it accordingly.

To determine the data type of a table column you'll need to access the column metadata, for example, by [calling `odbc_result()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-result.php).

Your logic of determining if the value is "binary" or not is flawed, as other have mentioned. For example, the value represented by `0x656667` might look like a string "ABC" to you, but in fact it may be an integer value 6645351.

Comment: The issue is with non-printable characters that cannot be used in queries. I took a different route. If !ctype_print($value), I use strtoupper(hex2bin($value)). Then, it is always printable.